# Нужны ли ещё дефисы в предложении о группах жанра метал?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, синтаксис, приложение, дефис

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать такое предложение:

*Это касается не только хеви-метал, но и блэк-метал и дэт-метал групп.*

Интересует, какие знаки нужны (или не нужны) для связки слов с "групп", какое правило тут действует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение, полагаю, должно выглядеть так:

***Это касается не только хеви-метал-, но и блэк-метал- и дэт-метал-групп.***

Научно-информационный «Орфографический академический ресурс АКАДЕМОС» Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН фиксирует [написание с двумя дефисами](https://orfo.ruslang.ru/search/word):

**нью-ме́тал-гру́ппа

панк-ро́к-гру́ппа

хе́ви-ме́тал-гру́ппа**

«Грамота.ру», соответственно, так и отвечает: «[Вы правы, нужны два дефиса](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291232)».

**Правило** ([Полный академический справочник под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp120.php)):

> **§ 120.** Следующие разряды существительных и сочетания существительных пишутся через **дефис**.
> <...>
> 4. Сложные слова с несклоняемой первой частью, выраженной существительным в им.п. ед.ч. без окончания (с нулевым окончанием), напр.: *джаз-оркестр, рок-ансамбль*.

«...Употребление висячего дефиса не зависит от слитного или дефисного написания сложных слов» ([ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59), § 112).